# how to store photo in android through dotnet webservices

Tags: android, web-services

I'm new in Android development want to save camera pic in oracle database using dot.net web services.

Please share your some knowledge to help me to implement this project.

Thank you so much

Comment: You must find some tutorials by using google.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/) for capture photo and save it to server

You can also use this for already captured Images

In You case First Create a web server for to Save Image to oracel db set path of that

check this answer for [`that`](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/669667/How-to-Store-and-retrieve-Image-in-Oracle-database)